# Prevent a bootstrap *open* modal from closing on bg click during runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

How do I stop an already open and instantiated **bootstrap modal** from closing on

- <kbd>Esc</kbd> keypress
- clicking on modal backdrop

I know about the `backdrop = static` option. But its before initializing the modal. Here I have the modal all nice and initialized. And its working all fine and dandy. Now in a user flow, I am supposed to prevent the modal from being "*close-able*".

**Update 1:** Just to clarify, I **don't** want that modal window to be *unclosable* (*if thats even a word*) from the beginning. I just want to modify the behaviors based on user activity and only for a specific flow. If the user doesn't follow that activity flow, I want the modal to retain the original behavior of being able to close on `backdrop click`.

Comment: You can use the [`keyboard` option](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options) and set the value to `false` to prevent the modal from closing on Esc keypress. what is the problem with `backdrop = static`?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the following solution.

**Bootstrap v3.xx**

```
jQuery('#paymentous').data('bs.modal').options.keyboard = false;
jQuery('#paymentous').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = 'static';
```

**Bootstrap v2.xx**

```
$('#paymentous').data('modal').options.keyboard = false;
$('#paymentous').data('modal').options.backdrop = 'static';
```

This will prevent an already instantiated model with `backdrop` option set to `false` (*the default behavior*), from closing.